# JavaScript UrlFetchApp

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, google-apps-script, javascript-objects

I am new to this and trying to access the content of my URL request, but JSON.parse is not helping at all.
My eventual goal is to set these values into a Google sheet.(GAS)

My output is the following:

```json
{"content":[{"id":1,"name":"BN","amount":200}]}
```

How can I access each of the elements in the array[]? (id, name, amount)

And, what is the name of this topic I am not understanding now?(code returning object nested in an array then nested in an object)

```
var url = "Https://content/units";

var token = customToken();




 var params = {
        "method": "GET",
        "muteHttpExceptions": true,
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": token,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
        

        
    };

var query = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,params);

var text = query.getContentText();
```

Was trying to get data from a page via URL but JSON parsing is not working and I do not understand what the object being returned means and how to manipulate it, tried looking for resources, but I do not understand the multi-nested object element in my output.

Comment: JSON.parse() just takes the stringified version and turns it into an object.  In your case  after parsing it, your array has only one element and it will be `content[0]` You should probably also consider reading a bit more about objects.  How to create and use them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: What is `URLFetchApp`? Is it pertinent to the question? It seems to be the only thing in the title of your question that makes it unique to the millions of other JavaScript questions. A little work there would not be remiss.

Answer (score 0):

Object response can be accessed as follows:
example output:

```
response = {"content":[{"id":1,"name":"BN","amount":200}]}
```

If the response always contains only one object key-value pair:

```
response['content'][0].name
//response[objectKey] -> returns value of object key
//response[objectKey][index] -> returns array value at given index eg:[0] from the object value
//response[objectKey][0].name -> returns the value of the specific key at the given array index
```